# AWS .NET Configuration Extension throwing 'Not implemented AppConfig type: application/octet-stream'

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-net, aws-parameter-store, aws-app-config

I am trying to use the [AWS .NET Configuration Extension for Systems Manager](https://github.com/aws/aws-dotnet-extensions-configuration) Nuget package (`Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager`) to retrieve configurations stored in AWS Parameter Store.

I am using the following lines of code taken from the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/aws/aws-dotnet-extensions-configuration):

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddAppConfig("AppConfigApplicationId", "AppConfigEnvironmentId", "AppConfigConfigurationProfileId", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

After running the code I am getting a `NotImplementedException` being thrown with the message:

```
Not implemented AppConfig type: application/octet-stream
```

Comment: @Ben did you check: https://github.com/aws/aws-dotnet-extensions-configuration/discussions/117

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the wrong method on the builder.

For obtaining values from AWS SSM's *Parameter Store*, you should be using `builder.AddSystemsManager`:

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
      {
          builder.AddSystemsManager("/my-application/");
      })
      .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Using `builder.AddAppConfig` is for obtaining values from AWS SSM's *AppConfig*, not Parameter Store.

Answer (score -1):

I found then if I stored data that was more complex than a single word in Parameter store it would give me the `NotImplementedException: Not implemented AppConfig type: application/octet-stream.` In that case you would need to use `.AddSystemsManager()` instead.